# Convert list to a list of pairs with nulls

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

From a list with type Magazine i want to create a list of pairs, but if the list has a odd number, the last item of the last pair should be null. In my code i can create a list of pairs, but if the list has a odd number, the last item doesnt go to the list.

**Magazine model:**

```
public class Magazine
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

}

public class PeoplePair : Tuple<Magazine, Magazine>
{
    public PeoplePair(Magazine item1, Magazine item2)
        : base(item1, item2 ?? CreateEmptyModel()) { }

    private static Magazine CreateEmptyModel()
    {
        return new Magazine { IsVisible = false };
    }
}
```

How I create the pairs list:

```
Magazines = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Count / 2)
            .Select(i => new PeoplePair(input[i * 2], input[i * 2 + 1])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After

```
Magazines = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Count / 2)
            .Select(i => new PeoplePair(input[i * 2], input[i * 2 + 1])).ToList();
```

you can check if the Array of input is divideable by 2: `input.Length % 2 == 0`

if not you can just add `Magazines.Add(new PeoplePair(input.Last(), null))`